# Custom terminator layout closes window when Ctrl+C is pressed

Tags: command-line, terminator

Hello I am running custom terminator layout with splitted windows, each of the windows run it's specific command. When I run the terminator everything is fine the command execute as they should, but when `ctrl+c` is pressed in any of the window the command stops and the window is closed. I remember running in on some article something saying something about that but now it seems I can't find it. So any help welcome and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your command like this.

```bsh
bash -c "trap $SHELL EXIT; <command>"
```

Anyway, you can also use [Terminator Layout Builder](https://pypi.org/project/terminator-layout-builder/) to manage layout easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc paste this script at the end of the file:

```
echo $INIT_CMD
if [ ! -z "$INIT_CMD" ]; then
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    setopt shwordsplit
    IFS=';'
    for cmd in $INIT_CMD; do
        print -s "$cmd"  # add to history
        eval $cmd
    done
    unset INIT_CMD
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
fi
```

2. In the custom command enter following:
   `env INIT_CMD="cd bla; command_1; command_2;" zsh`
   NOTE: Mind that if you have quotes you will have to escape them e.g. `env INIT_CMD="java -argument=\"tmp/\" -jar my.jar \"serverIP=127.0.0.1\" \"serverPort=8088\"" zsh`

I don't take the credit :) here is the full link: https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2015/11/28/terminator-multiple-custom-commands/

Hope it helps!